# How can I automate converting lines into columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a table with 2000 lines structured like this

```
company   product   targetJan   targetFeb   targetMarch   targetApril ...
Google    Docs      10          20          30            40
Google    Mail      13          25          45            70
```

That I want to covert to

```
Company  product  Date  Target
Google   Docs     Jan   10
Google   Docs     Feb   20
...
Google   Mail     Jan   13
...
```

I have no idea how to tackle this and am not particularly familiar with macros or vba.
How can I tackle this?

EDIT: I have recorded a macro that does the job but only on the first line that I specified. Now I need to figure out how to apply it to every 12 rows over the entire document: https://pastebin.com/D9yUHxZk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done without using a macro.  The formulas below fill a new table off to the right of your existing data:

[image]

These formulas, filled down from O2:R2 (respectively) give the results shown.

```
 =OFFSET($A$2,TRUNC((ROW()-2)/12),0)
 =OFFSET($B$2,TRUNC((ROW()-2)/12),0)
 =RIGHT(OFFSET($C$1,0,MOD((ROW()-2),12)),3)
 =OFFSET($C$2,TRUNC((ROW()-2)/12),MOD((ROW()-2),12))
```

Note that (for simplicity) I've changed your target headers so the month portion is the three-letter abbreviation.  If you want to extract a longer month name, that can be done using the MID() and LEN() text functions.

When you have filled in all the new data, you can delete the columns containing the old data if you want.  But first, select all the new data, copy it, and Paste Special > Values... so the data isn't lost when you delete the columns that it's derived from.

Answer (score 0):

To convert lines into columns (transpose):

- copy your range
- paste
- click on paste option (bottom right corner of your pasted array)
- click on transpose (T)

Otherwise your transpose example is not clear but if you want it more custom it is a good opportunity to learn a bit of vba/excel funtions. Just start by splitting the expected actions step by step.

good luck.

Comment: yes this works, but not when I have to do it on 2000 lines :) I have recorded a macro, but that is cell specific, I now need to somehow apply it to evey 12th line: https://pastebin.com/D9yUHxZk

Comment: The question isn't asking about transposing a range.